# Post specific data when specific div is selected php

Tags: javascript, php

How can I send data to my email when a specific field from a dropdown list is selected? I have two dropdown lists , the first one works and I recieve the data in the email but I get no data from the second one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
    if(name=='Spa')
          document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    else 
         document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
    if(name=='Masaj')
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
    else 
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
    if(name=='Impachetari')
         document.getElementById('div3').style.display="block";
    else 
         document.getElementById('div3').style.display="none";
    }
    </script>

<select name="options" id="options" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">       
            <option value="Spa">Spa</option>
            <option value="Masaj">Masaj</option>
            <option value="Impachetari">Impachetari</option>
            <option value="Pat sare salina">Pat sare salina</option>
            <option value="E-fitness"> E-Fitness</option>
        </select>

        <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Optiuni Spa: 
            <select name="div1">
                <option value="tubapasarata">Tuburi cu apa sarata</option>
                <option value="tubexterior">Tub Exterior</option>
                <option value="jacuzzi">Jacuzzi</option>
                <option value="sauna uscata">Sauna Uscata</option>
                <option value="sauna umeda">Sauna Umeda</option>
                <option value="salina">Salina</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you are submitting through ajax, you need to post that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "example@example.com";
    $email_subject = "Despre Example";


function died($error) {
    echo "Ne pare rau dar a intervenit o eroare. <br>";
    echo "Aceste erori pot fi regasite mai jos : <br> </br>";
    echo "$error <br> </br>";
    echo "Va rugam sa va intoarceti la pagina anterioara si sa reparati aceste erori.";
    die ();
}

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments']) ||
    !isset($_POST['date']) ||
    !isset($_POST['hour'])) {

        died("Ne cerem scuze,dar au aparut niste probleme cu formularul pe care l-ati trimis.");
    }


$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$options = $_POST['options'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$antibot = $_POST['antibot'];

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'Adresa de email este invalida. <br>';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'Numele este invalid.';
}

if(strlen($subject) < 3) {
    $error_message .= '* Subiectul scris nu este unul valid.';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Mesajul scris nu este unul valid.';
}

if(strlen($date) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Va rugam sa selectati o data completa. Ex: Zi / luna / an.';
}

if(strlen($hour) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Va rugam sa alegeti o ora completa. Ex: 14:00.';
}

if(strlen($antibot) > 0 ) {
    $error_message .= 'We don`t like spammers.';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

 $email_message = "Detaliile formularului mai jos.\n\n";

  function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }

$email_message .= "Nume: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subiect: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mesaj: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
$email_message .= "Data: ".clean_string($date)."\n";
$email_message .= "Ora: ".clean_string($hour)."\n";
$email_message .= "Optiuni: ".clean_string($options)."\n";

// Email Header

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->

Multumim pentru mesaj. Vom raspunde cat de curand posibil.

<?php

}
```

Comment: Actualy, how it is answering the question ?? It looks like a basic emailing stuff thru PHP ..

Comment: I just need something simple for my contact form. It is just 2 easy select options for a Spa.They select specific data from "options" and then other options appear on the form , specific div`s for what they select. I get the data for my "options" but the second dropdown-list won`t work.

Comment: check you select name are unique? like name='div1',name='div2'

Comment: yes , they are in order .. div1 / div2 / div3.. I want to make something like when they select the second option from the first list wich is "Masaj" the form to post only the specific services wich will be found in div2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you need a solution like this. you want to do like you did in javacript function. it is doing the same in php for the selected option get specific service.

```
$options = $_POST['options'];

    if($soptions=='Spa')
    {
    $service = $_POST['div1'];
    }else if($soptions=='Masaj')
    {
    $service = $_POST['div2'];
    }
    echo $serivce;
```

Comment: Some explanation of your understanding would help.